# MySQL ADD KEY meaning

Tags: mysql, database-design, table

This code below is creating a primary key on table User, but Im not understanding the second ADD KEY (C_NATIONKEY), do you know what is doing? Its something about foreign keys?

```
ALTER TABLE USER
ADD PRIMARY KEY (C_USRKEY),
ADD KEY (C_NATIONKEY);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per MySql documentation, KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

In your case ADD KEY will explicitly define index on that field.

Comment: In MySQL, the `PRIMARY KEY` is not just an `INDEX`, but also constrained to be `UNIQUE` and (for Engine=InnoDB), "clustered" with the data.